# Import vs File Read speed in Python

Tags: python, list, io

I'm working with an large list that I need to import into a Python script, and for my purposes the simplest and fastest ways of doing that I can think of are either using Pythons import function or directly reading from a text file. I was wondering which was faster and why.

How I go about importing the list:

Via importing:

```
from list_file import the_list
```

Via file read:

```
with open("list_file.txt") as f:
    the_list = []
    for item in f:
        the_list.append(item)
```

I know that importing comes with the risk of executing code you don't want to execute, but I was curious as to which was faster and what was going on "under the hood" so to speak to make one faster than the other.

Comment: Time it and find out.

Comment: Remember that python source files are usually compiled to byte-code while imported the first time. The second time you import it, it will be substantially faster. You can also use `py_compile` to do it in advance.

Comment: "Simplest" and "fastest" are usually at odds. Could you comment on what your actual use case and constraints are?

Comment: Are the items strings? There are additional formatting required in the first case, do you care about that?

Comment: Doing each method with slightly altered code, there is no difference with a list of 10k names as strings. Doing them repeatedly import wins hands down as after the first time it is compiled. However, reading the data from a pickled version of the list was about 5x faster than either of the oneshots.  Give the `timeit` package a try and if you can't get it working post what you tried and I will show you want I did to get the numbers I see.

Comment: I have a cronjob calling a python script every 10 minutes. A list I need within this python script is a large list of url's (which are strings) which I'd prefer not to put at the beginning of the python script because it is very long.

Comment: @JonSG Using timeit with number=1, I get 0.00018687 for import and 7.3026e-05 for file read.
With number=1000 I get 0.00081243 for import and 0.0514677 for file read.
I'm unfamiliar with pickling nor have I used py_compile so I'll have to take a look into that.

Comment: the second can be shortened into `the_list = open("list_file.txt").readlines()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's look directly at the timeit code I used:

```py
import timeit

setup = """
import pickle

def test_import():
    from foo import data
    return data

def test_read():
    with open("foo.txt", "r") as file_in:
        return list(file_in)

def test_pickle():
    with open("foo.pkl", "rb") as file_in:
        return pickle.load(file_in)
"""

print(timeit.timeit("data = test_import()", setup=setup, number=1))
print(timeit.timeit("data = test_read()", setup=setup, number=1))
print(timeit.timeit("data = test_pickle()", setup=setup, number=1))
```

With an initial list of 10k names as strings with one iteration I get results like:

```
0.00120
0.00103
0.00031
```

Sometimes the import is faster than the read, sometimes slower but the pickle always wins hands down. Of course if you increase the `number` parameter, the import will win.

Now, since you are not familiar with `pickle` you might think of it as working a lot like the `json` package (`loads()` and `dumps()`).

If it helps, here is the code I used to create "foo.pkl" from "foo.py"

```py
import pickle

from foo import data
with open("foo.pkl", "wb") as file_out:
    pickle.dump(data, file_out)
```

Comment: After some reading and looking at comments above, if I'm understanding correctly, import is faster than a file read if it gets called multiple times because it gets compiled to byte code on the initial call, but pickle wins out because it is already byte code?

Comment: That would be my interpretation as well. Though I am not really an expert here.